# Why does hint::spin_loop use ISB on aarch64?

Tags: assembly, rust, arm64, spinlock, armv8

In `std::hint` there's a [`spin_loop`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.spin_loop.html) function with the following definition in [its documentation](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/hint/fn.spin_loop.html):

> Emits a machine instruction to signal the processor that it is running in a busy-wait spin-loop (“spin lock”).
>
> Upon receiving the spin-loop signal the processor can optimize its behavior by, for example, saving power or switching hyper-threads.

[Depending on the target architecture, this compiles to either](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/hint.rs.html#110):

- `_mm_pause`, A.K.A. [the `pause` intrinsic](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/documentation/cpp-compiler-developer-guide-and-reference/top/compiler-reference/intrinsics/intrinsics-for-sse2/miscellaneous-functions-and-intrinsics/pause-intrinsic.html) on x86
- [`yield` instruction](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/dui0473/m/arm-and-thumb-instructions/yield) on 32-bit arm
- [`ISB SY`](https://developer.arm.com/documentation/ddi0596/2021-06/Base-Instructions/ISB--Instruction-Synchronization-Barrier-) on 64-bit arm (aarch64)

That last one has got my head spinning a little bit (). I thought that `ISB` is a lengthy operation, which would mean that, if used within a spin lock, the thread lags a bit in trying to detect whether the lock is open again, but otherwise there's hardly any profit to it.

What are the advantages of using `ISB SY` instead of a `NOP` in a spin loop on aarch64?

Comment: Good question.  AArch64 also has a YIELD instruction but the description of it in the Architecture Reference Manual doesn't really make sense.  It speaks of performing a task that could be "swapped out" or that the PE could "suspend and resume multiple software threads".  But those seem like OS functions.  I don't see how a hardware instruction could accomplish that, unless it was actually a trap, and there's no indication of that.  Its pseudocode description is `Hint_Yield();` but that function is not defined in the manual.

Comment: @NateEldredge: That description sounds like it was written in case anyone wants to design a core with coarse-grained multithreading that does switch-on-stall (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multithreading_(computer_architecture)#Coarse-grained_multithreading), unlike SMT (e.g. AMD Zen, or Intel Hyperthreading) or an in-order barrel processor.  On a core like we're used to with mainstream Intel/AMD CPUs, yes, that description for a YIELD instruction makes no sense.  (Although presumably you're handle it like x86 PAUSE, just yielding the front-end to the other hardware thread(s).)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had to dig into the Rust repository history to get to this answer:

The `yield` has been replaced with `isb` in [`c064b6560b7c`](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/commit/c064b6560b7ce0adeb9bbf5d7dcf12b1acb0c807):

> On arm64 we have seen on several databases that ISB (instruction synchronization
> barrier) is better to use than yield in a spin loop.  The yield instruction is a
> nop.  The isb instruction puts the processor to sleep for some short time.  isb
> is a good equivalent to the pause instruction on x86.
>
> [...]

So essentially, it uses the time it takes for an `ISB` to complete to pause the processor, so that it wastes less power.

Peter Cordes explained it nicely in one of his comments:

> ISB SY doesn't stall for long, just saves a bit of power vs. spamming loads in a tight loop.